# Recursive processing of a directory not working correctly

Tags: javascript, image-processing, macros, imagej

I've been combing this forum looking at other examples of code similar to mine but I still have not been able to solve the issue.

I am processing images in Fiji/imageJ using a macro code. The code is meant to recursively search a given directory for image files (in this case .vsi files) and convert them to .tiff using the built in bioformats functions.

I have cobbled the following code together from several examples (I am not a programmer, I have a biology degree), and I am returning an error that the specified file does not exist just as I am about to actually process a file.

All of my images have the following general directory structure:

~/Brain_01/Slice_01/Slice_01_01.vsi

An actual example is as follows for the second image in this set:

~/K259_tlx3cre/K259_1of3_02/K259_1of3_01_02.vsi

I really, really appreciate all the help you guys provide! I am completely stuck right now and am just banging my head against the keyboard at this point. Also, I think I've followed all the rules for posting. If not please just point out the error of my ways.

Finally here is the macro code I have written so far:

```
Dialog.create("File type");
Dialog.addString("File suffix: ", ".vsi", 5);
Dialog.show();
suffix = Dialog.getString();

inDir = getDirectory("Choose Directory Containing " + suffix + " Files ");
outDir = getDirectory("Choose Directory for TIFF Output ");
setBatchMode(true);
processFiles(inDir, outDir, "");
print("Done!");

function processFiles(inBase, outBase, sub) {
  flattenFolders = false; // this flag controls output directory structure
  print("Processing folder: " + sub);
  list = getFileList(inBase + sub);
  if (!flattenFolders) File.makeDirectory(outBase + sub);
  for (i=0; i<list.length; i++) {
    path = sub + list[i];
    //upath = toUpperCase(path);
    upath = path; //the previous line cause some problems
    if (endsWith(path, "/")) {
      processFiles(inBase, outBase, path);

    }
    else if (endsWith(upath, suffix)) {
        print("Importing " + suffix + " = " + list[i]);

            run("Bio-Formats Windowless Importer", "open=path color_mode=Default view=Hyperstack stack_order=XYCZT");

            print("Blue...");
            selectImage(1);
            title1 = getTitle();
            run("Blue");

            print("Green...");
            selectImage(2);
            title2 = getTitle();
            run("Green");

            print("Red...");
            selectImage(3);
            title3 = getTitle();
            run("Red");

            print("Merging Channels...");
            run("Merge Channels...", "red=&title3 green=&title2 blue=&title1 gray=*None* cyan=*None* magenta=*None* yellow=*None* create keep");

            print("Converting to RGB");
            run("RGB Color");

            saveAs("Tiff", path);
            run("Close All");
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks to some great help from Jan, and the people on the ImageJ mailing list, I was able to get my code working well enough to do what I need to do! The code below is working well enough to batch convert a directory full of .vsi files to .tiff using the functions I need. I haven't tried changing my code to Michael's suggestion to change endsWith(path, "/"... if i get that working in the future I will post it also.

```
Dialog.create("File type");
Dialog.addString("File suffix: ", ".vsi", 5);
Dialog.show();
suffix = Dialog.getString();

inDir = getDirectory("Choose Directory Containing " + suffix + " Files ");
outDir = getDirectory("Choose Directory for TIFF Output ");
setBatchMode(true);
processFiles(inDir, outDir, "");
print("Done!");

function processFiles(inBase, outBase, sub) {
  flattenFolders = true; // this flag controls output directory structure
  print("Processing folder: " + sub);
  list = getFileList(inBase + sub);
  if (!flattenFolders) File.makeDirectory(outBase + sub);
  for (i=0; i<list.length; i++) {
    path = sub + list[i];
    //upath = toUpperCase(path); only need if the file extension is case sensitive
    upath = path; //avoids the previous line
    if (endsWith(path, "/")) {
      processFiles(inBase, outBase, path);

    }
    else if (endsWith(upath, suffix)) {

        print("Importing " + suffix + " = " + list[i]);

        run("Bio-Formats Windowless Importer", "open=["+inBase + path+"] color_mode=Default view=Hyperstack stack_order=XYCZT");

        print("Stack to Images...");
        run("Stack to Images");

        print("Blue...");
        selectImage(1);
        title1 = getTitle();
        run("Blue");

        print("Green...");
        selectImage(2);
        title2 = getTitle();
        run("Green");

        print("Red...");
        selectImage(3);
        title3 = getTitle();
        run("Red");

        print("Merging Channels...");
        run("Merge Channels...", "red=&title3 green=&title2 blue=&title1 gray=*None* cyan=*None* magenta=*None* yellow=*None* create keep");

        print("Converting to RGB");
        run("RGB Color");

        saveAs("Tiff", outBase + path);
        run("Close All");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the error message you get, you should be able to spot the issue: while your file sits at e.g. `inBase + sub + list[i]`, your `path` variable contains just `sub + list[i]`. So you should use something like:

```
run("Bio-Formats Windowless Importer", "open=[" + inBase + path + "] color_mode=Default view=Hyperstack stack_order=XYCZT");
```

for opening the file, and:

```
saveAs("Tiff", outBase + path);
```

for saving the output file.

If you also want to use the `flattenFolders` flag in your code, you should build your output path dependent on the state of `flattenFolders`, such as:

```
outputPath = outBase;
if (!flattenFolders) outputPath += sub;
outputPath += list[i];
```

By the way, there's no need to convert your path to uppercase with `toUpperCase(path)`, unless you want to use a case-insensitive file suffix. In that case, you can write:

```
if (endsWith(toUpperCase(path), toUpperCase(suffix))) {
    // process your file here
}
```

to allow both *.vsi* and *.VSI* as an input.

**Note**: The [script editor](http://fiji.sc/Script_Editor) of the [Fiji](http://fiji.sc/Fiji) distribution of ImageJ offers a [macro template](https://github.com/fiji/Script_Editor/blob/master/src/main/resources/templates/Macros/Process_Folder.ijm) to process folders recursively, you can open it via *Templates > Macros > Process Folder* in the editor.

Comment: You seem to have started a [new thread on the image mailing list](http://imagej.1557.x6.nabble.com/Recursive-processing-of-a-directory-not-working-correctly-tp5007797.html) a few days after my answer. (I'm linking it here so that other users with similar problems can find the discussion.) I also edited my answer to include [Michael Schmid's suggestion](http://imagej.1557.x6.nabble.com/Recursive-processing-of-a-directory-not-working-correctly-tp5007797p5007819.html) to use square brackets with file names containing spaces.

Comment: Thank you Jan! I will post my working macro code here as well for future users.